# Convert nested and complex form data into JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

I am expecting the json data in the following format from the form -

```
{
    courseId: 4,
    lectureId: 5010,
    popupTime: 3,
    questions: [
        {
            title: "Which is the Capital of India 2",
            _id: "5450dff18f7cde8b4ed4ae3d",
            answers: [
                {
                    answer: "Delhi",
                    correct: true,
                },
                {
                    answer: "Bangalore",
                    correct: false,
                },
                {
                    answer: "Mumbai",
                    correct: false,
                },
                {
                    answer: "Chennai",
                    correct: false,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            // second object in questions array.
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I design the form in the front end, so that the user can enter a question(can be multiple) and then can 
enter answers linked to that question. I even want to store a bit in the answers object that indicated whether it is
correct answer or not.(Typically got from `checkbox` or `radio button`).

So far I have tried -

```
 <form id="aj">
            <input type="text" name="questions[][title]" value="" placeholder="Question Title">
                <input type="text" name="answers[]" value="" placeholder="Answer 1">
                <input type="text" name="answers[]" value="" placeholder="Answer 2">
                <input type="text" name="answers[]" value="" placeholder="Answer 3">
                <input type="text" name="answers[]" value="" placeholder="Answer 4">
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>

$( "#aj" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var o = {};
        var a = $( "#aj" ).serialize();

       $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        console.log(o);
  });
```

So after serialization I am getting -

```
{ 
  questions: [ { title: 'Question 1' } ],
  answers: [ 'answer 1', 'answer 2', 'answer 3', 'answer 4' ] 
}
```

But I need the questions to be an `array of object` questions. And each object of question has an array of answers.

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: what specific problems are you having?

Comment: I have updated the question with what I am trying. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this by using classes and/or data attributes in your markup and giving your initial object some better defintiion.

HTML

```
<form id="aj">
    <div class="question">
        <input type="text" class="title"  value="" placeholder="Question Title" />
        <input class="answer" type="text" value="" placeholder="Answer 1" />
        <!-- other answers -->
        <div class="correct">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="correct_1" value="0" />1</label>
           <!-- other radios -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#aj").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var o = { questions: []};
    $('div.question').each(function (qIndex, qElem) {
        var answers = $(this).find('.answer').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        o.questions.push({
            title: $(this).find('.title').val()
            correct: $(this).find('.correct :radio:checked').val(),
            answers: answers
        });
    });

    console.log(o);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/se5xgha4/1/)**</kbd>